# laravel 5 insert date and time to database

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, laravel-5

I want to insert the current date(date and time) along with my form inputs on laravel 5 or 5.1 only. I have this code in `PatientController.php` but I'm not sure on how to include the current date.

```
public function create(Patient $patient, Request $request)
{
    // $post = $request->all();

    $data = [
        'pName' => $request['fname'],
        'pAddress' => $request['address'],
        'pBday' => $request['bday'],
        'pPhone' => $request['phone'],
        'pEcon' => $request['econ'],
        'pDreg' => dateTime('created_at')
    ];

    $patient->insert($data);

    return redirect('patient');
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Laravel will automatically create two `timestamps()` columns when generating a new database table via a migration

```
Schema::create('tasks', function(Blueprint $table)
 {
   ...
   $table->timestamps();
 });
```

Edit : If you want to manage timestamps you can do it in your model:

```
class YourModel extends Eloquent
      ....

      public static function boot()
      {

           public $timestamps = false;

           parent::boot();

           static::creating(function($model) {
              $dt = new DateTime;
              $model->created_at = $dt->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
              return true;
           });

          static::updating(function($model) {
             $dt = new DateTime;
             $model->updated_at = $dt->format('m-d-y H:i:s');
             return true;
          });
      }
```

Reference: http://laravelsnippets.com/snippets/managing-timestamps

Edit 2:

Backup Reference : https://web.archive.org/web/20151104131317/http://laravelsnippets.com:80/snippets/managing-timestamps

Answer (score 0):

Check laravel v5.1 on [Available Column Types].
To add your column do:

```
$table->timestamp('pDreg'); // TIMESTAMP equivalent for the database.
```

OR

```
$table->dateTime('pDreg'); // DATETIME equivalent for the database.
```

Then call `date()` function on yours `$date`.

```
$data = [
    'pName' => $request['fname'],
    'pAddress' => $request['address'],
    'pBday' => $request['bday'],
    'pPhone' => $request['phone'],
    'pEcon' => $request['econ'],
    'pDreg' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s')
]);
```